# cost of Windows 10 on the Pi

Tags: windows-iot

I know the beta is free but we are looking at a commercial application on the Pi.

Does anyone have a ballpark clue as the licensing cost for Win10 on the Pi?

Comment: Windows 10 IoT is available for use with the Pi, for free. This is in no way a cut down version of the Windows 10 you'll find on computers and tablets. If your after a desktop UI give Raspbian a look. If you are so concerned about licensing costs I suggest contacting Microsoft and explaining your situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Microsoft's ['Windows For Business'](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/windows-iot) pages:

> There is a SKU ‘Windows 10 IoT Core’ available at no royalty cost for
>   all our device makers that enables automatic OS updates via Windows
>   Update when connected to the internet.
>
> ...
>
> In addition, we also have an OEM exclusive SKU ‘Windows 10 IoT Core
>   Pro’ which provides an ability to defer and control updates. This SKU
>   can be licensed via distributors. Except for the servicing model
>   difference, the features are the same between these two SKUs of
>   Windows 10 IoT Core.

The terms and conditions for Windows IoT Core are available [here](https://www.windowsforiotdevices.com/), behind Option One. That's completely free, including non-deferrable updates.

The terms, conditions and costs of Iot Core Pro are more difficult to get hold of. Microsoft direct you to a [distributor list](https://www.windowsforiotdevices.com/distributor/index). The home pages of a couple of these do provide 'Get a quote' options but no prices. It looks like you're going to have to talk to an actual human to get more information.